# Using NSDate to create a 6 hour date window

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsdate, nspredicate

I have a bunch of NSDates in an array. I need to generate a function that makes each date into a number (a 6 hour window), like so:

```
Sept 17, 2014 12:00am to 5:59am = 2014-09-17-1
Sept 17, 2014 6:00am to 12:00pm = 2014-09-17-2
Sept 17, 2014 12:01pm to 6:00pm = 2014-09-17-3
Sept 17, 2014 6:01pm to 12:00pm = 2014-09-17-4
Sept 17, 2018 12:00am to 5:59am = 2014-09-18-1
```

I want to pass in a date and get the number back for part one.  And for part 2, I want to get the number from 2 times or 12 hours ago?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout NSCalendar and NSDateComponents. In general, you create NSDateComponents from your NSDate using an NSCalendar. That will give you hours, days, years, months, seconds as nice Integers. You can then use these values to group them.

For example:

```
NSDate * someDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar * gregorian = [NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendatIdentifier: NSGregorianCalenar];
NSDateComponenets * components = [gregorian components: NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate: someDate];
```

You can use the dateComponents the get hours and days, all other properties on it are invalid. If you want more, you need to specify those units too in the parameter of components: fromData;.